# "print to file" icon is not displayed in Gtk Print File Window

Tags: c, gtk

I am trying to print a Gtk Window using the print functionality provided by Gtk (e.g using api's like gtk_print_operation_run). **The Gtk Print Window does n't show the "print to file" icon in the general tab of the Gtk Print Window.** I am running this application in a Solaris 10 machine, architecture is x86.

Answer (score 0):

Just try configuring one printer on your solaris machine, After configuring one printer, your print to file option will also appear.

This might sound funny and magical, But i faced same issue and this resolved my problem. I dont know the root cause for the issue.